# Is a good practice to use Queryable.ProjectTo<DtoModel> inside a repository method, having more optimal sql queries instead?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, repository, automapper

As **Repository pattern** recommends, its methods should return **Data Access Objects**.

Using Queryable Extension method **ProjectTo** from **AutoMapper**(http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) on our DbContext objects, makes the sql query simpler and shorter, but it makes our methods to return **Data Transfer Objects**.

*DbContext.Books.ProjectTo().ToListAsync()* - will query only fields contained in BookDTO(*Only Id and Name* for instance), but not the entire object.

So, its a good idea to make our repository to return DTO objects and having instead more optimal sql queries ?

Answer (score 2):

The `DbContext` class is already a repository - so we just use the queryables directly on it. If you're wrapping the `DbContext`, then you can just expose the `DbSet` directly.